# Assist with passing json object forward on html form

Tags: php, json

Hello I have a multidimensional associative array I want to be able to send forward  using POST on an html form.  I thought this would be a simple matter but I think I am missing something.

here is where i encode the array into json:

```
$bottomInfoJson=json_encode($bottomInfo);

print_r($bottomInfoJson);
```

Just to show the json was properly encoded I printed it out and this is what i got:

```
 {
 "M1":{"amount":765,"instMrn":"100"},
"M2":{"amount":50,"instMrn":"100"},
"M3":{"amount":770,"instMrn":"100"},
"M4":{"amount":2159,"instMrn":"100"},
"M5":{"amount":145,"instMrn":"100"},
"M6":{"amount":500,"instMrn":"100"},
"M7":{"amount":7507,"instMrn":"100"},
"M8":{"amount":335,"instMrn":"100"},
"M9":{"amount":525,"instMrn":"100"},
"C10":{"amount":130,"instMrn":"100"}}
```

So I thought I could just pass this on a form simply since it is contained in the php variable...

Here is my form:

```
<form method='post' action="midMichSummary" enctype='application/json'>
<input type="hidden" name="sdate" value="<?php echo $sdate; ?>"/>

<input type="hidden" name="hbpb" value="<?php echo $hbpb; ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="bottomInfoJson" value="<?php echo $bottomInfoJson; ?>" />

<input type="submit" value="Summary->"/>

</form>
```

Basically all stuff is being passed fine except the json array - using print-r($_POST) at the destination shows me what has been passed...

So I am thinking there may be something additional i need to do to pass this properly - so I am hoping someone can help with this...

Comment: json_encode returns a string (a "json"). You can't print_r (which is for arrays) a string.

Comment: What is the use case of this? You should not need to send back _to the server_ a bunch of values you've just posted _from the server_.

Comment: Rather use a Session var to persist this data.

Comment: thanks for your comments Jeff - the use case is sending info from a page that is already figured out and nicely packaged in an array, and just being to be able to send it to a new page without doing all the stuff to "recreate it" on the new page... but i was able to get it to work with Hassam's help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you get exactly in the $_POST["bottomInfoJson"] variable, but in case you got something like this "{", then the issue should be in the double quotation, you can simply try replacing the double quotation here:

```
value="<?php echo $bottomInfoJson; ?>"
```

with single quotation

```
value='<?php echo $bottomInfoJson; ?>'
```

It should work